# Screen Brightness keeps automatically adjusting to 100%

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a late 2011 Mac book Pro, which I have kept in mint condition. Recently, my brightness has kept adjusting itself to full 100% brightness on the display, and keeps adjusting itself every few minutes even if it's still at 100% brightness. I have tried un-checking the automatically adjust brightness option and I still haven't been able to stop this from happening. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Since you have already un-checked the "Auto-adjust Brightness" option in the display settings, try resetting the System Management Controller (SMC). This may resolve the issues related to power management. Follow [these guidelines](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201295) to reset the SMC. One of the indicators that your SMC might need to be reset:

> The display backlight doesn't respond correctly to ambient light
>   changes on Mac computers that have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

*i turned off my keyboard and flipped it upside down and gave a good shake......then it stopped doing it... maybe something was stuck in the keyboard pressing down the dim up/down key*